# Does Thread Agility occur in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, threadpool

In ASP.Net a request can migrate from one thread to another (thread agility) :  http://piers7.blogspot.fr/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html

Can we see a request migrating from a thread to another using ASP.Net MVC?
If so, when? Are Filters, Controller Constructor and Action executed on the same thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.

For example, your controller might use async / await to load resources from an external web service.  Execution of that request will be paused during the async operation, and when it resumes, it will resume on any available thread from the thread pool

Comment: I also want to know when Thread Agility occurs. Tell me if i'm wrong but as long as my action isn't async, there is no thread agility. http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/async-and-await and http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Comment: TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern, which underlies async/await and the TPL) is the third async pattern put forward by .NET.  I *believe* following either of the previous patterns also allows thread agility in ASP.Net.  For a great discussion listen to http://www.hanselminutes.com/327/everything-net-programmers-know-about-asynchronous-programming-is-wrong (warning: hanselminutes.com is down as of this writing, but I expect it will be back up shortly)